# Classic ASP and IIS 7.5 on my LOCAL machine

Tags: iis, asp-classic, activex

I have inherited a classic ASP project and a VB6 Component (ActiveX .dll) that goes with it.

I would like to be able to debug this component by running it locally on my machine.

I have a Windows 7 Home Premium (64 bit) laptop.

I have setup IIS 7.5 locally (production is running IIS5), however, when I browse to the site (locally) I get:

Active Server Pages error '00000000'
Create object failed
?
An error occured while create object 'OBJECTNAME'
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01ae'
Class does't support Automation: 'ID of object in global.asa

**I'm not a server guy, so I don't have a lot of experience setting up IIS.** I want to setup this project locally so I can step through the COM object using the debugger.

What do I need to do to get this running?

Just as an FYI :

In the global.asa I have the following:

Then in the ASP I have the following call:

if ABC.propertyName = True then

...

It fails at that line.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the wrong object is getting run. I'd imagine this isn't an IIS problem as much as it's a COM automation issue - you'd probably have the same issue from VBScript. Go ahead, try a .vbs file!

So: Did you register the object with REGSVR32?

And does this look familiar?: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264512(VS.60).aspx

Comment: Tristan - the actual fix for this error was that I needed to change the Enable 32 bit applications = True and change the Manage Pipeline = Classic.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed - post it as your own answer! :)